# Loading a page from url does not work, but page work when I click Refresh

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I have a URL that displays a customer list like this:

```
http://domain.com/pls/apex/f?p=724:2:820875406836801:::::
```

The list of customers are displayed with the title being linked to Page3 & request has CustomerId

When I click the URL `http://domain.com/pls/apex/f?p=724:3:21712451478201::NO:RP,3:P3_CUSTOMER_ID:82`, Page 3 is loaded correctly with details of selected customer. But the "Update" and "Delete" action buttons never work.

But, if I click the browser refresh button and then try to perform an update or delete, it works.

I don't know where I could be going wrong. Can someone give me hints?

I am not using `BRANCH_TO_PAGE_ACCEPT` in my URL link definition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with the way the url was created. First of all, I should not set only 1 thing (Title) to be a url. It should be the entire div. Like below.

```
<li><div style="">
<a href="f?p=&APP_ID.:2:&SESSION.::NO::P2_PK_PROJECT_ID:#LINK#" rel="external">
<h3>#TITLE#</h3>
<p><strong>#BOLD_TEXT#</strong></p>
<p>#PLAIN_TEXT#</p>
</a></div>
</li>
```

A report row template with the above code was created. This template is used in my Customers List page. Now each customer is a link (Title, Name, etc). The link href is also hard-coded. Note that I am passing ProjectID:#LINK# #LINK# refers to a value like 1, 2 etc

Now clicking this, loads page 2 correctly and Apply Changes & Delete button are now clickable.

Comment: If this answer is to help others in your situation, could you show what your code was originally (e.g. you can edit your question)? I'm not clear on what exactly you've changed.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you have the session ID hardcoded in the URL on page 2:

```
http://domain.com/pls/apex/f?p=724:2:820875406836801:::::
```

The session ID is 820875406836801, whereas:

```
http://domain.com/pls/apex/f?p=724:3:21712451478201::NO:RP,3:P3_CUSTOMER_ID:82
```

The session ID has mysteriously been changed to 21712451478201. I'm not sure, but I suspect that you've hardcoded the session ID in your report on page 2. This has the effect of causing a new login session to be created when page 3 is opened (and maybe this is why the update/delete buttons don't work - but you haven't told us what the error message is so I'm not sure); refreshing the page may be restoring the session.

If I'm right, what you need to solve this issue is to use the session variable (`&SESSION.`) in your report on page 2 instead of hardcoding it, e.g.:

```
http://domain.com/pls/apex/f?p=724:3:&SESSION.::NO:RP,3:P3_CUSTOMER_ID:82
```

Comment: Actually, I copied the url in 2 different runs. That's why the session id is different. There is no hardcoding anywhere. But the issue still remains. Any other thoughts?